# can't install oro platform using this command sudo php app/console oro:install --env="dev"

Tags: php, linux, symfony, doctrine-orm, orocrm

trying to install oro platform using this command sudo php app/console oro:install --env="dev" but I get the following error :

> Dropping database schema...
>
> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
>
> doctrine:schema:drop [--dump-sql] [--force] [--full-database] [--em[="..."]] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-s|--shell] [--process-isolation] [-e|--env="..."] [--no-debug] [--jms-job-id="..."] [--current-user="..."] [--current-organization="..."] [--disabled-listeners="..."] command
>
> [RuntimeException]
>   The command terminated with an exit code: 255.

Answer (score 2):

Check your database parameters, something is wrong.

Comment: If you use 127.0.0.1 for the  database_host try to change it to the localhost and for the database_port: 3306

Comment: @DoruMardari My Magento Version 1.9.2.3, i have installed Bitnami OroCRM in Windows. After successfully installed then i going to Sync. The Sync is not complete i am getting an error like, Jobs Failed  1) oro_integration:sync_integration:1  2)  orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1  3)  orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1  4) oro_integration:sync_integration:1  5) orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1 all the Jobs Failed. My status error : https://justpaste.it/4rkcs  and log error : https://justpaste.it/61uta How can i solve the issue?